Reading an Excel file from within a Jetpack Compose environment
I am confident I have the correct dependencies in the gradle.build file but my issue seems to be that the App fails every time on an attempt to load
I started with this code
var path = "/Internal storage/Documents/Sweeps.xlsx"
var file= File(path)
var inputdata = FileInputStream(file )

var workbook = HSSFWorkbook(inputdata)
var sheet1 = workbook.getSheet("Handicap Index & Course Play...")
var row = sheet1.getRow(0)
var cell = row.getCell( 2)
var celldata = cell.stringCellValue

Log.i("MO","My Excel value is : "+ celldata)

However the app fails as soon as it tries to open the file.
As an alternative I added the Sweeps.xlsx file to the directory "Internal storage/Android/com.example.my_app/files" and seem to get the same error.
I am at a lost as how the internal data storage and paths work.
I tried multiple paths and removed spaces from file names to make it as simple as possible.  I think it is related to the file not being in the right location or the path not being properly specified.  Ideally I want this spreadsheet shared between app so I would like it in a documents location but for now would settle for app specific file location.

"App fails" do you mean the app crashes, then can you provide the crash log?
And you are directly using the path. Does you app have Storage Permission? Try to use Document picker instead.

I have done further investigation and an updated question is located under the title "Reading a file from the download directory".  I know the name of the file and the location and while the file contents will change regularly the name and location will not so I don't want to use a file picker.  The issue is a permissions issue which I have yet to solve.
